# Value of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin^2x\cdot xe^{-x} dx$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos^2x\cdot xe^{-x} dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I got these value by WolframAlpha:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin^2x\cdot xe^{-x} dx=\frac{14}{25}$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos^2x\cdot xe^{-x} dx=\frac{11}{25}$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin^2x\cdot x^2e^{-x} dx=\frac{136}{125}$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos^2x\cdot x^2e^{-x} dx=\frac{114}{125}$$

I tried to generalize and explain these, but I stuck on generalization of their partial integrations.

Please give me good way.

Answer (score 5):

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\cos(ax) e^{-bx}\,dx = \text{Re}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left[-(b-ia)x\right]\,dx =\text{Re}\left(\frac{1}{b-ia}\right)=\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}$$
and $\cos^2(x)=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$, $\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)$. Moreover
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} x^k\cos(ax)e^{-bx}\,dx = (-1)^k \frac{d^k}{db^k}\left(\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @Jack D'Aurizio's answer
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin^2(x)\, x^n \,e^{-x} dx=\frac{1}{20} \left(10-5^{-n} \left((1-2 i)^{n+1}+(1+2 i)^{n+1}\right)\right)
   \Gamma (n+1)$$
This generates the sequence
$$\left\{\frac{2}{5},\frac{14}{25},\frac{136}{125},\frac{1896}{625},\frac{37008}{3125
   },\frac{186096}{3125},\frac{5622912}{15625},\frac{197140608}{78125}\right\}$$

Now , you can easily do the other one using $ \sin^2(x)+ \cos^2(x)=1$ and
$$\int _{0}^{\infty}  x^n \,e^{-x} dx=\Gamma (n+1)$$